# setting Radcombobox value atfer inserting item

Tags: c#, telerik

I have a RadComboBox and I would like to set the value of the Combobox to the item that was just created. How do I get the index of the last item that was created and how do I set the control? I have tried to hardwire the control like this. Thanks.

```
        if (cmb_Contacts.SelectedIndex != 1 && cmb_Contacts.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            cmb_Contacts.DataValueField = mMgt.ContactID.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution that you could try
declare a variable to hold the last item
then get the count of the items currently in the cmb_Contacts

```
int lastitem = 0;
lastitem = cmb_Contacts.Items.Count;
this.cmb_Contacts.SelectedIndex = lastitem - 1;
```

Comment: Yes I tested it.. something quick and simple.. happy coding Pavlov are you from Russia by chance..?

Comment: My dads side is from Lithuania, it is a small street in russia ;) I am 100% american, which sounds exciting outside of the country.

Comment: LOL I just noticed the name.. my ex wife is Slovic that's why I asked.. happy coding